# application of intermediate value theorem in root finding

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

suppose we have following function

$f(x)=x^2+10\sin(x) $

we should show that there exist number $c$ such that $f(c)=1000$

clearly we can solve this problem using intermediate value theorem for instance

$f(0)=0$

$f(90)=90^2+10\sin(90)=8100+10*1=8110$

and because $1000$ is between  these two number we can see  that there exist such $c$  so  that $f(c)=1000$

am i right? thanks in advance

Comment: this is a correct argument

Comment: Before you can come to that conclusion you probably want to notice that the function is continuous but then yeah it follows quite easily.

Comment: yes sure  about continuous fact of course

Comment: $\sin(90) = 1$?? The argument to $\sin$ is not number of degrees, it's in radians. All you can say is $\sin(90) \ge -1$, so $f(90) \ge 8100 - 10 = 8090$. The rest of the argument still works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x) = 2x+10\cos x$ is clearly positive if $x\geq 6$, hence our function is increasing over the interval $[6,33]$ and since $1000$ is between $f(6)$ and $f(33)$, there is some (only one) $c\in(6,33)$ such that $f(c)=1000$.

Comment: sir you have chosen  $33$ randomly right ?

Comment: @datodatuashvili: it is about the square root of $1000$. I just took an integer $n$ that grants $f(n)>1000$.

Comment: ok thanks in advance for your efford